# How to copy all struct elements into a char * array in C

Tags: c, strcpy

I am sorry if the question is not clear or sounds stupid but I am very new at C/C++ programming so please be gentle

I have a struct like this

```
struct foo
{
    int a = 05;
    char b;
    char c;
}foo_var;
```

I have a char pointer array as

```
char *Arrpointer[sizeof(foo)];
```

..
Then i intialised b and c using foo_var.b and foo_var.c

I want to copy all the contents i.e a, b, c values into this *Arrpointer

I thought of using strcpy

```
strcpy(Arrpointer, ????)
```

but as you can see I am stuck
Any help will be appreciated

Also this Arrpointer is dynamic meaning that any no. of struct contents should be easily stored in it like Struct foo, bar etc. etc.

Comment: This makes no sense. You seem to not be able to distinguish between arrays, pointers, arrays of pointer (which you have here) and pointers to arrays. Go read about them and come back with a **meaningful** question when you're done.

Comment: post actual code next time too

Comment: Moreover, please take into an account that copying int into char isn't wise as `sizeof(int)==4` and `sizeof(char)==1`, so you would probably lose 3B of information. If you need to convert integeral type into string try to use `itoa()`. Anyway, if you desire only to access structure as an array of bytes you can simply type `char *arrptr = &foo_var;`

Answer (score 0):

Since neither variable is a string so `strcpy` is not appropriate; `memcpy` is what you need.  However you have an array of pointers that are unitialised and do not point to anything valid.

```
Arrpointer[n] = malloc( sizeof(foo_var) ) ;
memcpy( Arrpointer[n], foo_var, sizeof(foo_var) ) ;
```

Creating `Arrpointer` with as many elements as there are bytes in `struct foo` seems unlikely to be what you intended.  Another problem is that once you have copied the structures, you no longer have any information to determine what structures are stored, or what size they are, so the whole "design" is suspect, but if the question is simply as per the title rather than the somewhat confused body then:

```
memcpy( pointer_to_destination, pointer_to_source, size_of_data ) ;
```

is the generic answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use strcpy to copy int or char. If you want to format data into a string in memory, you can use snprintf http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/.

```
result_string = malloc(MY_SIZE)
snprintf(result_string, MY_SIZE, "%d %c %c", foo_var.a, foo_var.b, foo_var.c)
```

Your Arrpointer is by no means dynamic - it is an array of a fixed size.
If you want arrays of dynamic size, you need to learn about malloc and free.